# Is there a way to build Dot chart of Raphael in HighChart?

Tags: raphael, highcharts

We want to plot activity by hour and day like here - 
g.raphaeljs.com/dotchart.html

Is there a way to do this in HighChart? I have looked around quite a bit but I can't find it.

Any pointers will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use scatter chart as demonstrated here: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter

Comment: A scatter plot is not anywhere close to the dot chart seen in Raphael. They are only loosely related. In Raphael's dot chart, dots are sized based on the magnitude of the value. In a scatterplot, the location of the dot indicated the value. Semantically, the information derived is different between the two chart types. The Bubble Chart is closer to the desired goal, but still not quite the same as Raphael's dot chart.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a Bubble Chart, to get close. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble

Although this chart is still not quite what you see in Raphael JS' dot chart.